# Lost BRP card – should I replace it or wait for WP extension to be filed?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I lost my BRP card (I have a Tier 2 ICT visa) and subsequently reported the loss to the Home Office on January 15, 2018. My visa was valid until May 25, 2018. Since my employer was anyway planning to file a visa extension, I called the Home Office and checked if I needed to file for replacement of the BRP or wait for 1-2 months for my company to file a visa extension (which will anyway result in a new BRP card being issued). I was told that I could wait for my company to file for a visa extension.

Unfortunately, it has taken quite a long time for my company to decide on my extension in the UK and it was confirmed just today. The company will take another 2-3 weeks from now to file the extension. However, by next weekend, 3 months will have passed since I lost my BRP card. As per the Home Office website, you need to apply for a replacement BRP within 3 months of losing it, else there could be a 1,000 GBP fine and deportation.

I want to know if I should file for a replacement BRP immediately (it will cost me around 100 GBP overall) and let my company file for my visa extension in another 2-3 weeks time. I am not sure if filing for extension will supersede the replacement process or both will happen in parallel, in which case I will get 2 BRP cards, one after another (one with the original end date of May 30, 2018 and another with the extended date).

Or should I wait for 2-3 weeks more (in which case I would end up spending 1-2 weeks more than 3 months and could result in a penalty). Or should I call the Home Office and take their advice?

Any pointer on this would help.

Comment: You do realize that without your BRP you can be classified as an illegal alien, don't you ? `or we may shorten your permission to stay` Did you miss this portion on the BRP letter ? Not sure why you want to jeopardize everything to save £100.

Comment: Yes, Got it. Silly me !!! Thanks for puting some sense in my brain. I shud have realised this earlier..

Comment: This is entirely off topic.  It belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 4):

> it will cost me around 100 GBP overall

VS

> else there could be 1000 GBP file and deportment.

Weigh your options and pick one. I would immediately apply for a new BRP card even if your employer was going to get you a new one in the coming weeks.

Keep your stay legal today, worry about *2-3 weeks* when you get there. £100 is a small price to pay.

That process overlap is then not your problem, you apply for a replacement as advised by them and if that results in a procedural clash that's for them to deal with. You will not incur any penalties just because you're due for a renewal soon after an application for replacement.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for puting some sense in my brain. I shud have realised this earlier !!